# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'WebApplication4.InteraFaces.IAllClothes' while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I got an error: `InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'WebApplication4.InteraFaces.IAllClothes' while attempting to activate 'WebApplication4.Controllers.ClothesController'`.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using WebApplication4.Data;
using WebApplication4.Data.Mocks;
using WebApplication4.Data.Repository;
using WebApplication4.InteraFaces;

namespace WebApplication4
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private IConfigurationRoot _confString;

        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment hostEnv)
        {
            _confString = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(hostEnv.ContentRootPath).AddJsonFile("dbsettings.json").Build();
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppDBContent>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_confString.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddTransient<IAllClothes, ClothesRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IClothesCategory, CategoryRepository>();
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Clothes}/{action=List}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Error]

Comment: What do both the `Program.cs` and `ClothesController` look like?

Comment: What is the constructors for `ClothesRepository`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)